# Is it wrong to allocate enough memory to a union for just one member?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, language-lawyer, unions

Is it possible to allocate memory that's enough to hold only a specific union member? I mean something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

union u;

union u{
    int a;
    long b[4096];
};

int main(){
    union u tmp = {.a = 42};
    union u *u = (union u*) malloc(sizeof(int)); //not malloc(sizeof(union u))
    memcpy(u, &tmp, sizeof(int));
    printf("u::a = %lu\n", u -> a);
}
```

`sizeof(union u)` equals to `sizeof(long[4096])` and it would be wasting of memory to allocate `4096 * sizeof(long)` to hold  a single `int`.

Is it possible to do such a thing like the one above? Or is it undefined behavior?

Comment: I have the feeling a union is not what you want. What's your actual problem?

Comment: A union needs the complete size of the union (i.e. `sizeof(union u)` in your case). Anything else is invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Any reference?

Comment: Not right now (or I would have posted an answer). But just think about it logically: Your pointer `u` is pointing to enough memory to hold a single `int` value. What is the use of the `union` here? It makes no sense. And if something makes no sense, then it's a high probability that it's not correct (and probably UB). Having e.g. `int *a = malloc(sizeof *a); *a = tmp.a;` could make sense, but not what you have.

Comment: The `printf` at the end certainly has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because `union`  can contain only one member at a time.  Standard: `an object with union type can only contain one member at a time`. So what's a problem with making the union object conating `int a` and allocating only memory enough to hold this `int a`.

Comment: Then why even use a union? I can understand the use of unions for network packets (for example), where the members are different structures or single variables. But the union is the *whole* union, not a part of it. If you want to copy a part out of the union, you only copy that single part out to a matching object. Pretending that a union is only a single member, ignoring the rest, is the bad thing you're doing. An object is the *whole* object, you can't just pick and choose parts of it.

Comment: Why not have a union of `int` and `long*`, and dynamically allocate the array of 4096 `long`s?

Comment: Did not your compiler warn about mixing specifiers/types with `int a; ...  printf("u::a = %lu\n", u -> a);`?

Comment: `memcpy(u, &tmp, sizeof(int));` is conceptually amiss. `memcpy(&u->a, &tmp.a, sizeof u->a);` makes more sense - or just `u->a = tmp.a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to allocate memory that's enough to hold only a specific union member?

Yes.  Yet code must then not attempt to use members in the unallocated parts.

---

For clarity, the below uses `union ab` rather than `union u`.

Initial part of code: no issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

union ab;

union ab {
    int a;
    long b[4096];
};

int main(){
    union ab tmp = {.a = 42};
```

Assigning a pointer to scant memory is not an issue unto itself.  Although for cast is not needed and I find allocating to the size of the object/member more informative (easier to code, review and maintain) than allocating to the size of the type.

```
    // union ab *u = (union ab*) malloc(sizeof(int)); //not malloc(sizeof(union ab))
    union ab *u = malloc(sizeof u->a);
```

The copying/assignment has no problems as the memory pointed to by `u` is sufficient.

```
    memcpy(u, &tmp, sizeof(int));
    // or 
    u.a = tmp.a;
```

Printing is a problem as code is using a mis-matched specifier.  On the corrected code, no issue in accessing the member `.a`

```
    // printf("ab::a = %lu\n", u -> a);
    printf("ab::a = %d\n", u->a);
```

So far no problems.

Some new code is a problem as code attempts to read via `u`, outside allocated memory - this is *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
    temp = *u;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer why it is invalid usage of union. `N1570::6.2.5p(20)`:

> A union type describes an overlapping nonempty set of member objects,
>   each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct
>   type.

It means the union object must have enough memory allocated to hold each member of the union, but it's overlapping. In my case it is not legal use of union since I allocated memory enough to hold only one of them.

Comment: Disagree.  In the code example, the _union_ `*u` is never used, only the member `u -> a`.  Certainly `tmp = *u;` is invalid.  As long as only the members(s) with the allocated memory are used, I see no problem.  The rules about `union` apply to pointer `u` _after_ it is de-referenced as a union.  `u -> a` is only an `int`.

Comment: @chux Now I'm really confused... So is the code example I provided in the question valid? I thought it was not because not enough storage was allocated so the object pointed to by `u` was not really union by the definition I provided.

Comment: The object `u` is a pointer type, not a union.  `u->a` in an `int`.  True, `*u` is not valid as there is not enough memory there, yet code does not use `*u`.  As long as code does not use `*u`, what problem do you see?  "the object pointed to by u" does not apply as code never de-references `u` in total.  (What compiler are you using regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894241/union-with-2-members/53894740?noredirect=1#comment94637627_53894241)?)

Comment: @chux `u->a` uses `*u`: it's defined in term of `*u`